# ASP.NET Membership Force HTTPS on PostBack

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have a login form on the home page of an ASP.NET 3.5 website which for performance reasons needs to be accessed with a standard HTTP connection. Since the normal postback for an ASP.NET page is relative call for the post, it would mean that when the browser posts the values are sent unprotected.

I would like to do one of two things to make this secure:

1. Force the Postback to be secure to the same page
2. Send the post to a different page using an HTTPS connection

Is there a way to implement option one?

I'm also looking at the Authentication Service, but looking at the URL reference it is using a relative path:

```
Sys.Services._AuthenticationService.DefaultWebServicePath = '../Authentication_JSON_AppService.axd';
```

I don't see a way to override this to put in an HTTP path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the form's action property with javascript to tell it to submit to a different page with https. I have done this and it works nicely.

You could also change it to submit to the same page with https, but I think asp.net would complain about that (not sure - never tried it).

sample script:

```
document.forms[0].action = "https://www.whatever.com/submit_page.aspx";
```

Comment: Could you point me to working version of this approach? I'd like to avoid writing a custom JavaScript function because of extra testing needed.

Comment: I can't show you mine, but the script is pretty simple - I edited my answer, since it doesn't display well in the comment.

Comment: Ray, are you doing this with an ASP.NET 3.5 Web Forms? I receive a viewstate validation error I tried that approch. Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

Comment: Actually, the page where I use this posts to an HttpHandler so there is no view state validation on the receiving end. If you are posting back to the same page, then you may not be able to do it. You could try turning off view state and page validation to see what happens.

Comment: I had to set enableViewStateMac for it to work. Matt Sollars had a similar recommendation only via server side coding, URL: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-security/WebPageSecurity_v2.aspx?msg=3373744#xx3373744xx

Comment: I need to do this also but mine needs to comply with PCI/DSS regulations.  This states that all logins must be actioned over SSL.  The issue with your answer is that when the security company scans the page they won't see the https URL in the form action as that doesn't get set until the button is clicked.  Also, if javascript is disabled it won't work.  Is there any way on the server side to tell it that certain fields should be posted via SSL to a different address?

Answer (score 2):

You could use Cross-Page posting:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx

Comment: Wouldn't Cross-Page posting go to a different page? I'm trying to keep on the same page because I have to send validation and error messages back on the same page.